Graphical estimation of geodesics
In this video, it is explained how time dilation causes gravity. It starts with going over the basics of general relativity, then goes over space-time diagrams, and finally explains geodesics and how they relate to gravity.
In 4:35, it takes for granted a graphical method for estimating geodesics, by tracing circumferences and watching where do they cut the gridlines.

But I cannot understand why does this work. So, independently of if the physics part is right or wrong, can somebody explain me if the graphical estimation of geodesics method provided here is ok?

Videos like this are designed to create an illusion of understanding; unfortunately, they are useless from the mathematical standpoint. (If one tries to make sense of what he says, basically nothing is right or even meaningful.) If you want to learn something mathematically meaningful about general relativity, consider reading the book "Semiriemannian geometry" by O'Neill.

@MoisheKohan I almost completely agree with you. I am aware of that issue. But in this particular case I was asking about the graphical estimation of geodesics.
